# How can I do my own typesetting and still use ctrl-m in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I'm a new Lyx user, and yes I've read the tutorial.

Lyx won't let you add two spaces or two blank lines when you want to.  If you switch to Verbatim font, then you type as you please but ctrl-m is disabled so you have to use Insert->Inline Eqn which is slow and irritating.  Is there any way defeat these irritating features, so that I can type what I want to type but also us ctrl-m?

EDIT:  Either enabling spaces in Standard or storing ctrl-M in Verbatim would work.  Or if there is some other setting that let's both work at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, it is not.

Comment: Jerry: Yes, there is, but may I ask why you need to do that? You can add multiple spaces with Ctrl + space, and multiple line breaks with Ctrl + enter, but particularly the last thing is usually the wrong thing to do. Depending on what you want to achieve, there will be other methods that are better.

Comment: Irritating feature? `:)` Allow extra space spaces misstyped between words of a sentence is irritating feature. But if you really wanted that for some reason ... menu `Insert` → `Formatting...`  → `Protected space` or some other of the several types of horizontal spaces.

Comment: @Fran  That didn't fix the problem, that just gave me one space.  I want to be able to press the spacebar and get spaces, you know the way keyboards work.  That works if I use Verbatim, but then I can't use ctrl-m.

Comment: Ctrl+enter at the start of an empty paragraph (when you hit enter you start a new paragraph) won't work, but if you do it at the end of a paragraph with text in it, it does work. That is the wrong thing to do though. It doesn't end the paragraph. If you want more space between paragraphs in general, go to Document -> Settings -> Text layoyut, and set the "Vertical space" to what suits you. To add more space in specific cases, Insert -> Formatting -> Vertical space.

Comment: I have no idea what Ctrl-M even does for Lyx. Are we sure the details and intricacies of each and every editor are on topic here? I don't mind either way, just saying.

Comment: @JerryGuern Do not expect to use LyX like Word. LyX will not allow you to add  very easily wrong formats, as several spaces between words , or several blank lines  between lines, but is not very difficult do that:  `Ctrl+Alt+(space space space space space)`  or  `Ctrl+(Enter Enter Enter)` you will do  what  you want (and most times that will be the wrong way to format the document correctly).

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  I'm starting to think I shouldn't be using Lyx for my purposes.  I just want to type notes and format equations, not fight with a typesetting program.  Is there some other freeware that's as good as Lyx for eqn editing but will also let me type what I want to type?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  Oh, but I got ctrl+Enter to work, it just didn't work at the beginning of the new line.  Thanks for the help.  If you want to put your comment below as an answer, I'll Accept it.  I realize I'm not using Lyx that way it's intended, but this info was very helpful.

Comment: I don't know of other alternatives, but I've never looked for any either (I don't even use LyX). This may sound arrogant or something, but it may be that you just need learn more about how LaTeX and LyX works, so that you can work with, rather than against, LyX, and possibly rethink the method you use for typing notes (can you give an example where you need multiple spaces?). Or it may that LyX just isn't for you.

Comment: @Ingmar There are lots questions about specific features of (La)TeX editors, so yes, I'd say so. (That said, LyX isn't actually an editor, in the sense that e.g. TeXworks or TeXstudio are. It is a graphical frontend to LaTeX that displays a simplified version of the output rather than the code, and lets you make documents without writing any code. Ctrl + M just adds inline math (`$ ... $`).)

Comment: @JerryGuern it could be that what you want is a Markdown editor. Many of those support LaTeX style typesetting (either via MathJax or KaTeX, which are both Javascript emulations of LaTeX) and some of them are more-or-less Word-like in the way the editor works. You have to know the LaTeX syntax for writing equations though. I use Typora on the Mac, but there are probably other good choices on all platforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're not exporting to any other format, it's probably more OK to ignore the LaTeX side of things. In the case that PDF is a desired output, the LaTeX side should *not* be ignored, and see the old answer below.

Go to Document --> Settings --> Local Layout, and add the following:

```
Style Standard
    Category              MainText
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Paragraph
    LatexName             dummy
    ParIndent             MM
    ParSkip               0.4
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Block, Left, Right, Center
    LabelType             No_Label
    FreeSpacing           1
    KeepEmpty       1
End
```

This modifies the *Standard* style to allow multiple spaces (`FreeSpacing 1`) and empty paragraphs (`KeepEmpty 1`). This will allow you to add spaces and newlines as you will, while not disabling math mode.

I guess the *Save as document defaults* button will make this default for new documents as well.

### Old answer

Well you can, but in general you probably shouldn't. There will probably be better ways of achieving what you're actually trying to do. That said:

- Adding multiple spaces can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> (the LaTeX equivalent is inserting a `~`).
- Adding multiple line breaks can be done with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, with the caveat that it doesn't work in an empty paragraph (the LaTeX equivalent is adding a `\\`)

Comment: Thank you!  For those who are wondering, I have premature arthritis, and my handwriting is deteriorating.  I use Lyx to jot math notes and work through problems the way I used to use scratch paper.  I don't even Export to other formats.  So I want to just space things out how I want to see them, while still being able to use inline equations.  It was terribly annoying to discover that Lyx needlessly disables ctrl-m in Verbatim, forcing me to use the mouse and dropdown menu every time.  I wish engineers thought about such things a little more.

Comment: @JerryGuern From a LaTeX perspective, it makes sense to disable Ctrl+M in verbatim, because it's not possible to insert math mode in verbatim mode. The point of verbatim is to print the content exactly as is, so `\begin{verbatim}$\int\,dx$\end{verbatim}` will show you a dollar sign, a backslash, etc. while outside of verbatim you will see an integral sign followed by dx. When you've selected verbatim from the dropdown, you're in such a verbatim environment, and there can be no inline math inside that. (ctd.)

Comment: @JerryGuern If you end that verbatim mode, the next piece of content will be in a new paragraph, and hence on a new line. In other words, there is a reason for why it is the way it is. You can define a keyboard shortcut to jump from verbatim to math, but that math will be placed on a separate line. I don't know if it's possible to customize LyX to behave differently.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right.  I was able to cut-and-paste incline eqns into my Verbatim sections but not create them there.  But still there's no reason they couldn't have had a mode where text works like Verbatim but inline equations still work there.

Comment: @JerryGuern No, I was rather guessing at why there is no such thing by default. However, your comments did make me think a bit, and I realized after some rummaging around that it's possible to do just what you want, so see the updated answer.

Comment: Ah, this answer is even better!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @JerryGuern  Although the  answer of Torbjørn is excellent (+1), be careful what you wish for. If you want to print or share your notes you will need to export to PDF and this way the blank lines will be ignored and the spaces will be protected (`~`)  avoiding a good paragraph format. The export to HTML will be also bad. IMHO the right solution  is (1) understanding that LyX is not a WYSIWYG editor (i.e., what you see is NOT what will get) and  (2)  just  maintain pressed the `Ctrl`  if you cannot avoid the temptation to force yourself  extra spaces or lines.

Comment: @Fran  Thanks. Yes, that's probably the approach I'll take if I'm ever preparing notes to send to others.

Comment: @JerryGuern May be sometimes you'll want to print your notes to read on A4 paper, and then you'll be glad to allow to LaTeX takes care of these things. By the way, `Documents` → `Settings...` → `Text Layout` → `Paragraph separation` → Check `Vertical space` and set it so some noticeable length (to BigSkip, for instance) and you will notice that very rarely you will need `Ctrl+Enter` to see your text better also in the screen.